# Fast compression of large (100 MB ) text file with byte values in it

Tags: performance, compression

I have a large text file of size in order of 100 MB to compress. It has to be fast (12-14 seconds). What algorithms I can consider and what will be the expected compression ratio for them?
I got some file compression algorithms like FLZP,SR2,ZPAQ,Fp8,LPAQ8,PAQ9A.... which are performant among these ? The time limit is strict for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined what performance criterion you are looking for: more speed or more compression ? LZ based compressor (FLZP, LZO, LZ4, LZHAM, Snappy, ...) are the fastest. The PAQ compressors use context mixing for each bit, so they are slow but offer the best compression ratios. In between you can find things like Brotli, Zstd (they both offer a wide range of options to tune speed/compression) or the older Bzip/Bzip2. Personally I like BCM for its great speed/compression compromise and its simple code: https://github.com/encode84/bcm.

Comment: I mentioned the time limit for me. I expect best compression ratio but also the algorithm should abide by the time limit.

Comment: The time limit is a constraint, not a performance definition. Within the time limit, if you prefer a faster algo (say < 2 sec) with limited compression ratio, then go with a LZ compressor (Zstd and Brotli have many levels to play with). If you are OK with a compression time close to the time limit, then CM based compressors will provide better ratio. It remains to be seen if CM compressors are fast enough on your hardware.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithms that you have picked are the most well compressing in the world. Therefore, they are slow.

[There are fast compression algorithms made for your use case.](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=#complete=1&hl=en&q=fast%20data%20compression) Names such as LZ4 and Snappy come up.